# TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined on es6 model

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I want to set JSON API in es6 model but I get this error 
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined

JSON API:

```
{
      "type": "user",
      "id": 2,
      "attributes": {
        "username": "madelynn81",
        "email": "taylor63@mills.biz",
        "first_name": "Emile",
        "last_name": "Veum",
        "created_at": "2018-11-17 11:48:13"
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "http://test.test/api/v1/user/2"
      }
    }
```

es6 model

```
class UserModel {
    constructor(data) {
        this.id = data.id;
        this.first_name = data.attributes.first_name;
        this.last_name = data.attributes.last_name;
        this.username = data.attributes.username;
        this.email = data.attributes.email;
        this.created_at = data.attributes.created_at;
        this.link = data.links.self;
    }

    get getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    set setId(value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

    get getFirstName() {
        return this.first_name;
    }

    set setFirstName(value) {
        this.first_name = value;
    }

    get getLastName() {
        return this.last_name;
    }

    set setLastName(value) {
        this.last_name = value;
    }

    get getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    set setUsername(value) {
        this.username = value;
    }

    get getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    set setEmail(value) {
        this.email = value;
    }

    get getCreatedAt() {
        return this.created_at;
    }

    set setCreatedAt(value) {
        this.created_at = value;
    }

    get getLink() {
        return this.link
    }

    set setLink(value) {
        this.link = value
    }
}
```

how can i fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question how you're using the getter to get the value. One issue: your set/get pairs should be named with the same property name. They should be named differently from the property holding the value. For example: `_id` for the value property name, and `id` for get/set name.

```js
class UserModel {

  constructor(data) {
    this._id = data.id;
    this._firstName = data.attributes.first_name;
  }

  get id() {
    return this.id;
  }

  set id(value) {
    this._id = value;
  }

  get firstName() {
    return this._firstName;
  }

  set firstName(value) {
    this._firstName = value;
  }

}
const data = {
  "type": "user",
  "id": 2,
  "attributes": {
    "username": "madelynn81",
    "email": "taylor63@mills.biz",
    "first_name": "Emile",
    "last_name": "Veum",
    "created_at": "2018-11-17 11:48:13"
  },
  "links": {
    "self": "http://test.test/api/v1/user/2"
  }
}

const user = new UserModel(data);
console.log(user.firstName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of which are your goals, but generally in javascript is used a simpler syntax, and objects are much like arrays.

Here's a quick example:

```js
    const data = {
      "type": "user",
      "id": 2,
      "attributes": {
        "username": "madelynn81",
        "email": "taylor63@mills.biz",
        "first_name": "Emile",
        "last_name": "Veum",
        "created_at": "2018-11-17 11:48:13"
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "http://test.test/api/v1/user/2"
      }
    }

    const user = { 
      id: data.id,
      firstName: data.attributes.first_name,
      // other props,
    };

    console.log(user.firstName);
```

In fact if you take notice, your data itself is already an object.